# TestNG with DataProvider runs successfully but Eclipse View is not updated correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse

**Problem:**

When I run a TestNG test using a `DataProvider` providing a large number of test cases, the Eclipse view for TestNG is not appropriately updated. It stops updating at a random point, and the progress bar indicates that the tests are still running. However, the console shows that all tests have been terminated.

For the MCVE below, I used Eclipse 2019-03 and TestNG 6.14.3, but I'm facing this problem since several years, with different Eclipse versions, different TestNG versions, and on different machines.

**MCVE**:

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNgTest {

    @DataProvider(name="data")
    public final Object[][] getTestData() {

        Object[][] data = new Integer[1000][];

        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            data[i] = new Integer[]{i, i};
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="data")
    public void test(int actual, int expected) {
        assertEquals(actual, expected);
    }
}
```

**Console Output of MCVE:**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
PASSED: test(0, 0)
PASSED: test(1, 1)
PASSED: test(2, 2)
[...........]
PASSED: test(997, 997)
PASSED: test(998, 998)
PASSED: test(999, 999)

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1000, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1000, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

**Output in TestNG-View:**

[image: TestNG-View]

Anyone facing the same problem? Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using maven project?

Comment: @Muzzamil: No, it is not a maven project. But if I convert it to a maven project, I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried reproducing this and I haven't been able to do that, using the sample that you have shared.

For what its worth, my project is a Maven project that uses TestNG `7.1.0` as the dependency.

OS : OSX (10.15.2)
Eclipse : Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) Build id: 20190314-1200
TestNG eclipse plugin :

```
Name : TestNG
Identifier: org.testng.eclipse.feature.group
version: 7.0.0.201908240652

Name : TestNG M2E (Maven) Integration
Identifier: org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature.feature.group
version: 7.0.0.201908240652

Name: TestNG P2 Feature
Identifier: org.testng.p2.feature.feature.group
version: 7.1.0.r202001120626
```

I dont see the eclipse plugin stall. Please take a look at the attached screenshot below. You could consider upgrading to the versions that I have mentioned (including TestNG)

If this continues to be a problem, I would suggest that you please file a bug in the TestNG eclipse plugin project : https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse

[image]

Comment: Thank you Krishnan! I converted my project to a Maven project and used TestNG 7.1.0 - I still have the same problem. I tried it on Windows 10 and on Windows 7.

Comment: @user7291698 - But you still haven't told us the TestNG eclipse plugin version that you are using. Please edit your question and include that information.

Comment: It's written in the question: 6.14.3

Comment: @user7291698 - Which is why I am asking you to please upgrade. That is NOT the latest version of that plugin.

Comment: Now I tested it with the newest Eclipse (2019-12) and the newest TestNg Eclipse plugin (7.0.0) - still the same problem.

Comment: @user7291698 - In that case, I would suggest that you log a bug in the project (Link I have shared in my answer).